# What are these lines when you merge git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I am new to merging git

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
    import '../styles/components/Outline.scss';
    =======
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    >>>>>>> master
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
    import { createStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
    import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
    import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
    import CheckCircle from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle';
    import Lock from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
    import LockOpenIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOpen';
    <<<<<<< HEAD
    import AuthenticationDialog from './shared/AuthenticationDialog';
    import firebase from '../firebase';
    import { Event } from '../models/analytics';
    import { LessonOutlineData, LessonOutlineItemData } from '../models/data';
    import { toY } from '../util/scroll';
    =======
    import { DrawerScrollRequest } from '../models/state';
    import '../styles/components/Outline.scss';
    import { computeScrollYIntoView } from '../util/scroll';
```

As you can see I am trying to merge master into a branch.
But I don't know what these lines are trying to say

Comment: This means you have a merge conflict: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging . The stuff in between `<<<<<< HEAD` and `======` is your changes that conflict with the changes on `master`, which is the stuff between `======` and `>>>>>> master`

Comment: http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflicts.html my material. No tracking, no monetizing.